# StartActivityForResult from browser

Tags: android, android-intent, browser

In Android, if you want to **launch an activity** and have that activity return a result you do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ....
}
```

---

If you want an activity to be **launched from the browser** you can write some HTML like this:

```
<a href="intent://HOST/#Intent;scheme=SCHEME;package=com.example.package;end"> Link </a>
```

---

**Question**:

Can you launch an activity from the browser and have that activity return a result to the browser?

I don't think it's possible but if anyone has any idea, please let me know. If you have an source that explain how to do this, I am happy to make a POC and report my findings.

Answer (score 0):

> **basically its not possible**

since followings concerns are not clear.

1. How will you handle results.
2. Where you where handle results.

Comment: It could be possible that the Android browser launches the activityForResult and then calls a Javascript function that you registered somehow with that result. Technically the browser could do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

> StartActivityForResult from browser is not possible.

As per the chrome developer guide, the basic syntax for an intent-based URI is as follows:

```
intent:
   HOST/URI-path // Optional host 
   #Intent; 
      package=[string]; 
      action=[string]; 
      category=[string]; 
      component=[string]; 
      scheme=[string]; 
   end;
```

**It do not provide any callback parameter, in which you can get callback, so it is not feasible.**

For more details visit https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible (as others have stated). However, you could have your `Activity` launch an URL in the browser which could then show the "result". This would be a way to have your `Activity` "return a result" to the browser. The URL launched could be static HTML page, or some JavaScript code or whatever.